# Conditional Probability Question - Please Help

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Messages relating to the status of an industrial system are transmitted to a monitoring
station via an internal transmission network. During periods of low network traffic,
1.2% of these messages have transmission errors, but during periods of heavy network
traffic the error rate is 4.7%.

Given that the traffic levels are low for 78% of each day, what is the probability that a
randomly chosen message was transmitted during a high traffic period and also had a
transmission error?

I dont know why, but i am having problems with this question.

so far i have my events as:

let "E" be the event "error has occurred"

Let "T" be the event "traffic is low"

Pr(T)=0.78

Pr(E|T)=0.012

Pr(E|¯T)=0.047

Is this correct so far?

**UPDATE**

So the answer is 0.01034, Thanks.

What is the proportion of messages in the last question that will have a transmission error?

Pr(E)=Pr(ET U E¯T)

=Pr(E|T) Pr(T) + Pr(E|¯T) Pr(¯T)

=0.012*0.078+0.047*0.22

=0.0197

What is the probability that a message from the first question which has a transmission error was transmitted during a period when the traffic levels were high?

Pr(¯T|E)=[Pr(E|¯T) Pr(¯T)]/Pr(E)

=(0.047*0.22)/0.0197

=~0.5249

Please tell me these are correct :)

Comment: There's no need to use *conditional probability* computation here. The answer is simply $(1-0.78)\cdot0.047$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct so far. All you need is $P({\overline T})=1-P(T)$ and then the answer is $P(E,{\overline T})=P(E|{\overline T})\times P({\overline T})$

Comment: So the answer is 0.01034, Thanks.

What is the proportion of messages in the last question that will have a transmission error?

Pr(E)=Pr(ET U E¯T)
=Pr(E|T) Pr(T) + Pr(E|¯T) Pr(¯T)
=0.012*0.078+0.047*0.22
=0.0197

What is the probability that a message from the first question which has a transmission error was transmitted during a period when the traffic levels were high? 

Pr(¯T|E)=[Pr(E|¯T) Pr(¯T)]/Pr(E)
=(0.047*0.22)/0.0197
=~0.5249

Please tell me these are correct :)

Comment: I can barely read that.

Comment: Sorry, I am just getting used to the formatting.  I have updated my original post.